# SQL query to left join two tables based on different datetime types

Tags: sql, datetime, left-join

I have 2 table, first table_1 contains 2 columns (datetime and float)

| date | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-02-25 11:41:00 | 0.56 |
| 2020-02-25 11:42:00 | 0.59 |
| 2020-02-25 11:43:00 | 0.60 |
| 2020-02-25 11:44:00 | 0.65 |

I have another table called table_2 which contains 2 columns (integer and datetime).
However the time column has seconds in it.

| id | time |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-02-25 11:41:22 |
| 1 | 2020-02-25 11:42:35 |
| 1 | 2020-02-25 11:44:55 |
| 1 | 2020-02-25 11:44:11 |

I want left join on the second table. The resulting output should look like

| id | time | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-02-25 11:41:22 | 0.56 |
| 1 | 2020-02-25 11:42:35 | 0.59 |
| 1 | 2020-02-25 11:44:11 | 0.65 |
| 1 | 2020-02-25 11:44:55 | 0.65 |

Kindly request to please suggest an sql query to left join a datetime with seconds to a datetime without seconds

Comment: The `JOIN` type isn't going to help you standardize your data. You need to remove the seconds from table_2, whatever `JOIN` you end up using. If you remove the seconds, a standard `JOIN` would give the desired output you want given the input data.

Comment: Always include your actual Database (with version) when asking SQL questions.  `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements are also much preferred to tables.

Comment: You want to join on the date part only? Then you need a function to extract that part. What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This should keep the query sargeable which any string based solution will not.

```
select t2.*,t1.value
from #test2 t2
left join #test1 t1 ON t1.thedate = DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, 
t2.thetime), 0)
```